# How can I compare two methods of measuring variables for a set of objects?

Tags: agreement-statistics, metric

I have a set of objects for which I measured the variables in two different ways. How can I determine whether these datasets overlap well in the feature space? I was thinking about calculating some correlation coefficient between the two datasets, but I would like to know if there is a better metric or test for this kind of problem.

Comment: Maybe you want to see if the two methods agree? Agreement is not the same as correlation, look into [tag:agreement-statistics], maybe add it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @kjetil b halvorsen put me on the right track. Since my variables  are continuous, I first visualized my data in a Bland–Altman plot (also called a Tukey mean-difference plot) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot).
). Then I used the ICC statistic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation).

Note: I found the paper of Haghayegh et al., 2020 to be very helpful (DOI 10.1088/1361-6579/ab86d6; unfortunately it's behind a paywall).